# Syntax: Applying IF to a cell range in Excel

Tags: excel, syntax, conditional-statements, named-ranges, ifs

I've been trying to write a formula to summarise in one cell the presence/ absence of certain values in a different range of of cells in Excel

So in the one table and worksheet, I wrote

=IF(B1:F1=1,1,0) Formula 1

which is supposed to mean

If any of the values in cells B1:F1 are equal to 1, then note 1, otherwise not 0.

But somehow the syntax isn't working.

I've applied "" and ; and brackets right left and centre, but to no avail.

I'm pretty sure I done this before and it was pretty simple when I hit upon the right synstax, but the how and where fell through the colander which is my brain today :-?

Additionally I will want to ask the formula to apply another condition to the output cell which is 
=if (A1 = value n or certain values, 1, 0)  Formula2
Column A has numerically coded ordinal values 0-9, so an aexample of teh 1 conditions might be any of values 1, 2 or 9 in column, should produce a 1 in the result cell in which Formula 1 and 2 will be written.

So the result cell would contain somelike
=Formula1_or_Formula2_contain_certain_values, 1, 0)  Formula 3
Obviously the systax of Formulas 2 and 3 is awol, but I write to demonostrate the formulae intended purposes.

Comment: Too many questions under a question.

Comment: Please read how to create [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Comment: `IF(COUNTIF(B1:F1,1) = COLUMNS(B1:F1),1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make the first formula is like this:

```
=IF(SUM(B1:E1)>0,1,0)
```

No arrays, no problems :)

Comment: Even as an array it will only look at B1, It will need something else like: SUM,COUNTIF,MIN,MAX,... to actually do the iterations.

Comment: Now change any of the others and it will not change

Comment: @ScottCraner - yup, building array formula for something like this is a bit useless.